# Different quantity for Performance Block Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using the API, I was able to verify the order of block storage with a quantity of 2, it even gave me the correct recurring costs, but when actually placing the order, only one was ordered. Is this a limitation of the API? This is in FedRAMP/usgov environment.

Would it be better to loop through the order service call as opposed to specifying quantity as 2 in the order container?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quantity should not be specified to orders endurance or performace storages.

you can try sendning all the object storages that you need in the order like this RESTFul example:

```
{
    "parameters": [{
        "orderContainers": [{
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
            "location": "AMSTERDAM",
            "packageId": 240,
            "prices": [{
                "id": 45058
            }, {
                "id": 45098
            }, {
                "id": 45068
            }, {
                "id": 144005
            }],

            "osFormatType": {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Linux",
                "keyName": "LINUX"
            }
        }, {
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
            "location": "AMSTERDAM",
            "packageId": 240,
            "prices": [{
                "id": 45058
            }, {
                "id": 45098
            }, {
                "id": 45068
            }, {
                "id": 144005
            }],

            "osFormatType": {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Linux",
                "keyName": "LINUX"
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Notice that I am appending the storages in the "orderContainers" property.

this is the description for that property:

orderContainers

Orders may contain an array of configurations. Populating this property allows you to purchase multiple configurations within a single order. Each order container will have its own individual settings independent of the other order containers. For example, it is possible to order a bare metal server in one configuration and a virtual server in another.
If orderContainers is populated on the base order container, most of the configuration-specific properties are ignored on the base container. For example, prices, location and packageId will be ignored on the base container, but since the billingInformation is a property that's not specific to a single order container (but the order as a whole) it must be populated on the base container.
Type: SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order

see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much! And all orders within the container will show up in one invoice?